# Why won't any of my query buttons work on my php form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to lay out my MySQL data in a table on the page. Instead of directing the user towards other forms to perform the Add, Update and Delete queries, I instead opted to have the queries within the table in the form of buttons, Saving time and effort as rows can be added, updated or deleted right then and there. However now with my page, form and tables set up I tried establishing the queries that the buttons would have set to them. And after testing it out, nothing works, when I click any of the buttons, the fields just return to whatever they originally were before I changed them.

**Admin_Album_Page.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();
require_once 'ConnectorCode.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Albums </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_Albums SET Album_Name='{$_POST['albumname']}', 
Number_Of_Tracks='{$_POST['numberoftracks']}', Genre='{$_POST['genre']}', 
Artist_id='{$_POST['artistid']}' WHERE Album_id='{$_POST['hidden']}'";
mysqli_query ($conn, $UpdateQuery);
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM tbl_Albums WHERE Album_id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysqli_query ($conn, $DeleteQuery);

}

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Album (Album_Name, Number_Of_Tracks, Genre,  Artist_id) 

VALUES ('$_POST[uartistname]', '$_POST[unumberoftracks]', 
'$_POST[ugenre]', 
'$_POST[uartist]')";
 mysqli_query ($conn, $AddQuery);

}

?>

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT*FROM tbl_Albums");

?> <table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Album ID</th>
<th>Album Name</th>
<th>Number of Tracks</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th>Artist ID</th>
</tr>
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<form method = "POST">
<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="albumid" value="<?php echo $row     ['Album_id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="albumname" value="<?php echo $row['Album_Name']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="numberoftracks" value="<?php echo $row['Number_Of_Tracks']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="genre" value="<?php echo $row['Genre']; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="number" name="artistid" value="<?php echo $row['Artist_id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Album_id']; ?>"/></td>    
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
}  
?>
<form method="POST">
 <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="ualbumname" /></td>    
     <td><input type="text" name="unumberoftracks" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="ugenre" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="uartistid" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<p><a href="Admin.php">Return to main page</a></p>
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm trying my utmost best to call on my declared rows and use them within the query but all I get is a refreshed page with no change to the data from the rows

Comment: this for one thing `$_POST(unumberoftracks)` should be throwing you an error. Wrong type of brackets.

Comment: first if statement never ends with `;`, you have some white spaces in your `HTML`. Miss use of `(` in an array variable.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I noticed that beforehand and corrected it as I was writing out the code here. Apologies.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected it now, but it's not fixing anything

Comment: correct `$_POST(unumberoftracks)`. Set $_POST['unumberoftracks']

Comment: @FrayneKonok Just fixed that bit:) But it's still not working :(

Comment: Use error reporting. You are also open to SQL injections.

Comment: @chris85 I do have error_reporting active, but no errors are being defined.

Comment: You aren't checking the results of your queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: anything from `mysqli_error($conn)` added to the queries coming back?  if you're going to want to perform any kind of data manipulation, then add a header to redirect to the same page, see if that works. Just make sure you're not outputting before header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not a matter of redirecting them to the page, I initially had it like this before and it worked, the only issue was the data was being represented as a value improperly. The page updates as the data is updated, so there wasn't any need to redirect them before, and even when I check MySQL I was seeing no new data being added.

Comment: are `artist_id` and `album_id` defined as strings in database-table? Maybe they should be ints? But this would have shown you a mysql-error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If all your query is perfect then this will run perfectly.**

**Update Block**

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_Albums SET Album_Name='{$_POST['albumname']}', 
  Number_Of_Tracks='{$_POST['numberoftracks']}', Genre='{$_POST['genre']}', 
  Artist_id='{$_POST['artistid']}' WHERE Album_id='{$_POST['hidden']}'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);
}
```

**Delete Block**

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM tbl_Albums WHERE Album_id='$_POST[hidden]'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $DeleteQuery);
}
```

**Add Block**

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $uartistname = $_POST['uartistname'];
    $unumberoftracks = $_POST['unumberoftracks'];
    $ugenre = $_POST['ugenre'];
    $uartist = $_POST['uartist'];

    $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Album (Album_Name, Number_Of_Tracks, Genre,  Artist_id) VALUES('$uartistname', $unumberoftracks, '$ugenre', $uartist)";
   mysqli_query($conn, $AddQuery);
}
```

**Dynamic HTML Block**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT*FROM tbl_Albums");?> 
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Album ID</th>
    <th>Album Name</th>
    <th>Number of Tracks</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Artist ID</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>    
  <tr>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <td><input type="number" name="albumid" value="<?php echo $row['Album_id']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="albumname" value="<?php echo $row['Album_Name']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="numberoftracks" value="<?php echo $row['Number_Of_Tracks']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="genre" value="<?php echo $row['Genre']; ?>"/></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="artistid" value="<?php echo $row['Artist_id']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Album_id']; ?>"/></td>    
      <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/></td>
    </form>
  </tr>    
  <?php }?>    
  <tr>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ualbumname" /></td>    
      <td><input type="text" name="unumberoftracks" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ugenre" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="uartistid" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"/></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is just the re-representation of the Code. Let me know if anything wrong with this.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Where was I going wrong?

Comment: I don't change anything from your code, just correct all the white spaces and proper place of `form`, You place the form outside the `tr` which makes a break of table.

Comment: So what I did do was initially correct it was just my placement of my form tag that were wrong?

Comment: yes, and also some extra white spaces, because of that some of the function not operating correctly.

Comment: Actually no wait something else is happening, the add function is still not working

Comment: lets see the add function.

Comment: add ` action=""` attribute in the add section block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108426/discussion-between-jack-rogers-and-frayne-konok).